# WIT.AI how to post `context-key`

Tags: java, wit.ai

using Wit.ai HTML api.
Posting `/converse` message I get the response of `type:action` with action name, then I execute some my own code. How then make `POST` with `context-key` to wit API to get an answer from the robot?

Also how to trigger robot message when user do not need to say anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your own code (the action you need to run) is responsible for updating the context (e.g. adding a key "forecast" with value "sunny"). In your Wit.ai /converse calls, you provide the context in the body.

See the example in the documentation: https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526#post--converse-link

You can call your `send` action when you want to trigger a robot message.